# Why does the inverting amplifier not work with my separate circuit as an input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

[image]
Hi, I've set up these two circuits and they both work separately. But no matter what I do I cant seem to connect them (from where the blue probe is to where the wave input would be). I feel like im missing something simple.
Does anyone know how to help. 
I've also tried using a simple potential divider for an input, but with no luck...
    btw. Im kinda new to electronics so im probably being just dumb :/

Comment: Did you connect the negative terminal of the battery in hte left circuit to the "0V" point in the right circuit?  What are you expecting to happen, and what does happen when you connect the circuits?

Comment: To connect it I am getting rid of the LED and AC voltage source. I then connect where the blue prong is to R4. What I'm hoping to achieve is to simply invert the voltage. But the voltage at the joing point goes to 1 and the output is also 1.

Comment: Answer the very reasonable question!

Answer (score 2):

As asked in the comments, are you only connecting the circuits **with a single wire?**

That won't fly.

You're also markedly changing the first circuit - if you get a signal you are happy with at the "blue point" with the LED, try **leaving the LED in place** and connecting the "blue point" to R4 and the left hand circuit battery negative to the "0 V" of the right hand circuit.

If that works you can try with the LED removed (if the above is "changing two things" from how you have been trying it.)

Comment: Thank you very much. This has worked and still works after removing the LED.